# Lucene search creteria change the word

Tags: c#, search, lucene, lucene.net, examine

I use lucene for searching.

For each doc in index I have some field called "uniqueIdentifier" with type string.

When I want to find all items with "uniqueIdentifier" == "haaglanden", I use the next code:

```
var searcher = Examine.ExamineManager.Instance.SearchProviderCollection["RegionsSearcher"];
var searchCriteria = searcher.CreateSearchCriteria(BooleanOperation.And);
var temp = searchCriteria.RawQuery("+uniqueIdentifier:" + uniqueIdentifier);
```

In temp I see :

```
LuceneQuery: {+(+uniqueIdentifier:haagland)}
```

But "**haagland**" != "**haaglanden**".

And I can not find my docs.

How can I build query with "haaglanden"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause was in analyzer.

Swiched Lucene.Net.Analysis.Nl.**DutchAnalyzer** to Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard.**StandardAnalyzer**.